# Random Property Trouble VB

Tags: vb.net, function, random

```
  Randomize()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
        num1 = value
        num2 = value

        If TextBox2.Text = (num1 * num2) Then
            TextBox3.Text = " correct ! "
        Else
            TextBox3.Text = "sorry, try again"

        End If
```

I am having trouble getting the Num1/num2 to equal a number 1-10.

How would I code it so that num1 and num2 equal a number 1-10?

Comment: do you want num1/nume2 to be equal to a number between 1 to 10 or do you want both num1 and num2 to be between 1 to 10?

Comment: Between 1 to 10. The code will then generate a random question like "what is 6 * 7"

Comment: Use Random.  See my answer for the basics.

Comment: you are generating only one random number...just generate another one and assign to it to the num2 variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `num1 = value`
and `num2 = value`

Value is just a variable we are creating.

```
randomvalue = CInt(Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd() + lowerbound))
```

So for your code:

```
 Dim num1 As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))

 Dim num2 As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
```

This example uses the Rnd function to generate a random integer value in the range from 1 to 6.
VB

```
' Initialize the random-number generator.
Randomize()
' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates how to use .Net's Random class.  Use it instead of Rnd.

```
Dim prng As New Random

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim value As Integer = prng.Next(1, 11) '1-10 upper range is exclusive
    Dim num1 As Integer = prng.Next(1, 11) '1-10 upper range is exclusive
    Dim num2 As Integer = prng.Next(1, 11) '1-10 upper range is exclusive
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Randomize()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Dim num1 As Integer = value
        value = CInt(Int((10 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Dim num2 As Integer = value
```

this will work